# Get last insert ID of the query before the last?

Tags: mysql, pdo

How can I get the topic id? So I can redirect the user to his topic after he has posted?
If I switch it around then I cant insert topic_id in posts. Hmm.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO topics (subject, posted, first_post_id, last_post, last_post_id, forum_id) 
VALUES (:subject,:posted,:first_post_id,:last_post,:last_post_id,:forum_id)");
$stmt->execute(array(':subject'=>$subject,':posted'=>time(),':first_post_id'=>$cid,':last_post'=>time(),':last_post_id'=>$cid,':forum_id'=>$f));


$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (poster_id, poster_ip, message, posted, topic_id) 
 VALUES (:poster_id,:poster_ip,:message,:posted,:topic_id)");
$stmt->execute(array(':poster_id'=>$cid,':poster_ip'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],':message'=>$message,':posted'=>time(),':topic_id'=>$db->lastInsertId()));




header("Location: /thread/".$db->lastInsertId()); // This will get the post ID not topic ID that i want it to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a temporary variable:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare(/* FIRST QUERY */);
$stmt->execute();

$temp = $db->lastInsertId();

$stmt = $db->prepare(/* SECOND QUERY */);
$stmt->execute();

header("Location: /thread/".$temp);
```

Comment: Oh! of course! wow how couldnt i think of that i feel stupid now haha